# Bind to object's property with EnumDropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-5.2, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am wanting to use the @Html.EnumDropDownListFor and I'm having an issue.

This is what I have:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.DefaultProviderEnum, 
               "Select default provider", new { @class = "form-control", id = "pro" })
```

Where `DefaultProviderEnum` is of type `ProviderFormat`:

```
public enum ProviderFormat
{
    [Description("ASG")]
    ASG = 1,
    [Description("SCS")]
    SCS = 2
}
```

And I set it correctly in the model and it appears correctly when it loads. The issue that I have is when I post it I have to manually set it in my object instead of it binding to a property on my object, which is an int:

```
 model.CU.DefaultProviderInt = (int)model.DefaultProviderEnum;
```

Is there a way to bind the enum drop down to a property on an object and not have to set it this way?

Comment: What is `model.CU.DefaultProvider`? You mentioned the property is of type `ProviderFormat` and later you said it is of type `int`? You have omitted what `CU.DefaultProvider` does.

Comment: DefaultProvider is just an int on the CU object. I'm trying to set that with the DefaultProvider off of the model that is of type `ProviderFormat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.CU` object will also get bound (*binded?*) by the `ModeBinder` with whatever value has been provided on submit of the form.

So, in your form, you can have a hidden property like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CU.DefaultProviderInt, new { id = "cu-default-provider" })
```

Then add a `change` event handler to the `DefaultProviderEnum` dropdown and set hidden input's value with the `select` value.

```
$(function() {
    $("#DefaultProviderEnum").change(function(){
        $("#cu-default-provider").val($(this).val());
    })
});
```

Now when the form gets submitted, both the properties will have the same value.

---

There's another way to do this.
The above code won't work if you manually set the value of `DefaultProviderEnum` somewhere in your code. So, you can have a custom setter for the `DefaultProviderEnum` property:

```
private ProviderFormat defaultProviderEnum;

public ProviderFormat DefaultProviderEnum
{
    get { return defaultProviderEnum; }
    set
    {
        if (this.CU != null)
        {
            this.CU.DefaultProviderInt = (int)value;
        }

        defaultProviderEnum = value;
    }
}
```

But, this also might depend on the order in which `DefaultModelBinder` binds properties. (If `CU` is null when `DefaultProviderEnum` is being set, then this might not work. So make sure to init `CU` in model's constructor)

---

The third and the **best** way to do this is to manually cast the enum to int and set it to `CU.DefaultProviderInt`.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with what you have? If the field is bound to `DefaultProviderEnum`, then that's the only thing that will be set by the modelbinder, anyways, so some manual intervention would be required to set a different property based on that. There's no way to have the modelbinder set two properties based on one posted value, if that's the tree you're barking up.

However, you can simply have a property like:

```
public int DefaultProviderInt => (int)DefaultProviderEnum;
```

Then, it will always just return the int coercion of the enum's value, whatever that happens to be at the moment.

Comment: I was trying to bark up the tree of having the drop down populated by an enum using the helper for that and have the property it sets on an object that is an int. If I just change the default provider property from an int to the ProviderFormat enum, it will work like I want, just wanted to know if there was a way to use an int as the property it sets using this helper.

Comment: No. If you're posting an enum, you must bind to an enum.